# Access variable in main activity from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public String myString;

     ...

     public void updateString()
     {
         new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 this.myString = "TEST";
            }
         }
     }
```

}

The problem is that I need to update myString from the thread, but I can't access it. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples take a look at that

Comment: use a boolean, when true change the variable for example

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way make string global and update it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public String myString;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        updateString();
     }

     public void updateString()
     {
         new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0; i<10;i++){

                    myString=String.valueOf(i);

                    //log
                    Log.d("myString:",myString);
                }

            }
        }).start();

     }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `volatile`?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases create a custom class which would implement Runnable and pass myString as an argument to the constructor of the class, so when runnable object will be created, it would stored locally which can be accesed from run method whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getters and setters, for example:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public String myString;

```
 ...

 public void updateString()
 {
     new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             setMyString("TEST");
        }
     }
 }

 public void setMyString(String myString){
     this.myString = myString;
 }
```

}